# jQuery Add and remove class not working in a series

Tags: jquery, css

I have an input field that I want to have a pulsing highlight when user clicks enter. I figured I could do that by adding and removeing a class but it only seems to add it.

CSS

```
input.update-value {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px rgba(12, 141, 45, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 1px 5px rgba(12, 141, 45, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         0px 1px 5px rgba(12, 141, 45, 0.75);
}
```

JS

```
$(function()
    {
       var  testTextBox = $('.edit-device');
       var code =null;
        testTextBox.keypress(function(e)
         {
             code= (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            if (code == 13) 
            $(".edit-device").blur().addClass('update-value').delay(350);
            $(".edit-device").removeClass('update-value').removeClass();
            $(".edit-device").addClass('update-value').addClass();
            $(".delete-input").hide();
             e.preventDefault();
        });

     });
```

Comment: You have a simple syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`delay()` only works on animations, not on adding / removing classes. You'll need to use a setTimeout, or if executing the function multiple times, use a setInterval, like so:

```
$(function () {
    $('.edit-device').on('keyup', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var self = this, i=0;
        if (e.which == 13) {
            $(self).blur().addClass('update-value');
        }
        var timer = setInterval(function() {
            $(self).removeClass('update-value');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(self).addClass('update-value');
            },1000);
            i++;
            if (i>3) clearInterval(timer);
        },2000);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Muh2P/1/)

Comment: it needs to turn on and turn off three times. The setTimeout doenst seem to make it blink

Comment: @ndesign11 Add more setTimeouts to get your desired effect.

Comment: I tried that, doesnt work

Comment: Have you tried the `<blink>` tag :-) ???

Comment: @adeneo, AFAIK, I'm afraid that is not part of the standard

Comment: @Alexander - It was a joke! Try fiddling with something like this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Muh2P/1/) ???

Comment: that works. If you can update in the answer I can give you some credit. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following jQuery plugin, `$.fn.blink`.

```
$.fn.blink = function(cls, times, delay) {
    var $self = this.removeClass(cls);
    clearTimeout($.fn.blink.handler);
    !function animate(times) {
        if(times) {
            $self.toggleClass(cls);
            $.fn.blink.handler = setTimeout(function () {
                animate(times - 1);
            }, delay);
        }
    }(times * 2);
    return this;
};
```

Usage:

```
$(".edit-device").blink("update-value", 3, 350);
```

Blink **`3`** times the **`update-value`** classname with a delay of **`350`** milliseconds.

[See it here.](http://jsfiddle.net/gfQBz/)